# Codeigniter: Display only last date entry

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to display just the last date entry for a person in a table, taken from joined tables.

I only seem to able to display the first entry or all.

Controller

```
public function session_view($id)
    {
        $data['main_view'] = 'session_view';
        $data['view'] = $this->Swim_model->CRUD_read_session($id);
        $this->load->view('load_view',$data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function CRUD_read_session($sessionid)
    {
        return $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('sessionsandswimmers')
            ->join('child', 'ID = SwimmersID')
            ->join('swimmersawards', 'PersonID = ID')
            ->join('awards', 'AwardID = AwardsID')
            ->order_by('LastName')
            ->order_by('DateAwarded')
            ->where('SessionID', $sessionid)
        ->get();
    }
```

View

```
foreach ($view->result() as $row)
    {
            echo '<tr>'.$row->FirstName.'</td><td'.$row->LastName.'</td><td>'.$row->Description.'</td><td>'.$row->DateAwarded.'</td></tr>';
    }
```

Result

As you can see, there are several entries for each person (except 1st).

I need to display just the latest date entry for each person.

So there should only be 4 entries.

[image]

Table structure

sessionsandswimmers - each session has 4 swimmers

1   tempid Primary  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
2   SessionID   int(11)         No  None
3   SwimmersID  int(11)         No  None
4   SessionSeasonID int(11)         No  None
5   Year    int(11)         No  None
6   LocationSS  int(11)         No  None

child - gets the swimmers name

swimmersawards - multiple entries per child

1   PersonID    int(11)         No  None
2   AwardsID    int(11)         No  None
3   DateAwarded date            No  None

awards - gets the name of the award

Comment: You should add a group by in your sql query

Answer (score 0):

change `->order_by('DateAwarded')` to `->order_by('DateAwarded','DESC')` . Need to specify which type of ordering you want. And for just one entry per person use :

`->group_by('FirstName,LastName')`

Comment: Still gives me only the first entry.

Comment: maybe because the session id value? Because the piece of code I posted should do what you were asking.

Comment: The sessionid is the same for everyone.

Comment: then the problem is the way you are joining, can I have a look at the table structures of those ? You might need to use  'LEFT JOIN'

Comment: I've edited the question to show the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the result you displayed is the table structure. Where you want the latest entry by date for each "name". If this is right then follow,

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM `<your-joined-tables>` order by `date` DESC
```

Sorry I am not good with CI's query builder.
Hope it works.

Comment: ONLY the latest entry, so it should only show four lines, one for each person.

Comment: Don't you mean three names? Evie, Amita and Harry. Anyways, Select DISTINCT should do the trick.

Comment: There is 2 Evie in this example, surname is different.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. So, SELECT DISTINCT on the surname.

Comment: I can't work out how to use SELECT DISTINCT in CI - anyone?

Comment: Isn't that the same as using ->group_by('LastName') ?

Comment: Please understand the concept here. Syntax can be found (that's why I am not good in syntax). Get the result table how you have already got. Then apply DISTINCT on it and order by descending. DISTINCT eliminates duplicate entries.     $this->db->distinct();  this is the syntax for using it in codeigniter by the way.